# Meaning of . (period) when copying in a batch file

Tags: batch-file

I'm looking through some batch files out of curiosity/for the purpose of learning and I'm seeing one thing I haven't been able to quite make sense of. I'm sure it's something simple, but I don't want to simply run this file, for obvious reasons.

Similar to the following lines:

```
copy /Y "\git\MyProject\bin\Release\MyLib-1.dll" .
copy /Y "\git\MyProject\bin\Release\MyLib-2.dll" .
copy /Y "\git\MyProject\bin\Release\MyLib-3.dll" .
```

I know what /Y does from reading online, but what is the `.` doing? My first assumption was that it meant to copy the file to the current directory, but I was under the impression that's what the %cd% variable is for so I'm not quite sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The period refers to the current directory, from which the batch file was called. So, in this case, the 3 DLL library files will be copied to the current directory that called this batch script.

The /Y parameter will force them to be overwritten, if they already exist in the current directory.

Comment: So, they are copied to where the script lives, or where %cd% is set to? (like if I were to explicitly set `cd` to somewhere else in the script itself)

Comment: If your script lives in C:\BatchScripts and you call it from C:\SomeOtherPath, then the files will be copied to C:\SomeOtherPath. Unless, of course, you change the directory from within your batch file, or its initial working directory is set prior to calling the script. %cd% holds the current directory as a reference, but . equally does the same. It's the most direct and succinct syntax for the current directory.

Comment: To clarify further, if you cnange directory from within your batch file prior to this copy operation, it will copy the files to the directory you have changed to.

Answer (score 1):

It means the current directory, so in your `copy`-commands it means that you are copying the files to the current directory